# C++ calling constructor from another file

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have those 3 files of code, and I want to to print "Mountains were just created" from the constructor.
Could you tell me please where I am wrong and what I must to do?

Mountains.h

```
#ifndef MOUNTAINS_H
#define MOUNTAINS_H

class Mountains{
    public:
        Mountains();
        ~Mountains();
};
#endif
```

Mountains.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Mountains.h"

Mountains::Mountains()
{
    cout<<"Mountains were just created"<<endl;
}

Mountains::~Mountains()
{
    cout<<"Mountains are about to be destroyed"<<endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Mountains.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Mountains m();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would expect, "Mountains were just created", to be written to the console when I call `Mountains m();` This is not happening.

Comment: What does this do? It should work as you have it here.

Comment: Is it just me or do you have to do Mountains m = new Mountains(); ?

Comment: This is not a question as is. Stack overflow is here to answer questions, not debug your program. If I were to guess, you're not using the std namespace when calling cout. Either add std:: before each use of cout or add "using namespace std;" towards the top of Mountains.cpp

Comment: @hatkirby your code is wrong in C++: new creates a pointer, that cannot be assigned to a variable of type Mountains.

Comment: @gluk47 you are right, Mountains* m = new Mountains(); I suspect this isn't the problem, however, it's probably the lack of using namespace::std or perhaps the author is not linking properly. We can't really know without the actual error.

Comment: @hatkirby, in fact, this is the only problem I noticed. Both your code (assuming pointer) and the author's would print what needed as I guessed if `using namespace std` were in place.
You are right, yes. :)

Comment: As per the author's edit, I think the below answer is probably correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
Mountains m();
```

That is not a *default-initialized* `Mountains` object called `m`. It is a function called `m` that takes no parameters and returns a `Mountains`.

To create a *default-initialized* `Mountains` you need to do:

```
Mountains m;
```

or in *C++11*:

```
Mountains m{};
```

---

You are also missing the `std::` qualification when using things from the *Standard Library*, like `cout` or `endl`. That's assuming you don't do `using namespace std;`, although discoraged, in a relevant place.

Comment: Actually this is not the most vexing parse (though it is vexing). Most vexing is this situation: `T x(U()); /* function! */`

Comment: @GManNickG: True... do we have a name for this? _The mildly vexing parse_?

Comment: Heh, I don't know of a name but "mildy vexing parse" is clever enough for me. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm really new to the C++. When I try the "Mountains m;" I get error: "C:\Users\MAKRID~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHgHZYv.o(.text+0x55):main1.cc: undefined
reference to `Mountains::Mountains(void)'"

Comment: @makridelacos: Don't worry, its a common error. That is one of the reasons they invented the `{}` notation for construction in _C++11_

Comment: @makridelacos: Sounds like you are not including `Mountains.cpp` in the build